# why ubuntu does not show wifi icon correctly?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, icons, icon-themes

i had this issue in ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04 and now i have the same problem in ubuntu 21.10.
why ubuntu does not show wifi icon correctly?
please look at the screenshot i have attached, i have connected to the wifi but the icon does not display it correctly.

[image]

Comment: Does the network work OK? The question mark means a problem with DNS.

Comment: yes, it works perfect. i use vpn but that is not the problem because with the same vpn i do not have this problem in linux mint. also even when i disable the vpn in ubuntu the icon remains the same problematic shape.

Comment: I have the same icon on VPN. After updates is white again.